# Android: Forcing UI refresh immediately

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I'm trying to build an android app which contains a countdown timer and should display three images for an amount of time in each interval - a masking image for 200 ms, a stimulus image for 20 ms and another masking image for again 200 ms.

The app works with two threads - the main UI thread and the time management thread.

The problem is, that the UI thread doesn't refresh itself, because it sleeps in between and hence doesn't display any images.

I've searched many hours already to find a way forcing the UI thread to refresh itself immediately, but until now I'm unsuccessful.
The methods invalidate() or postinvalidate() for example don't do anything useful.

It would be great if anyone has a hint or a solution for this problem.

Thanks for your help.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button button;
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView textViewCounter;

    boolean buttonWasPressed = false;
    double startTime;
    double currentTime;
    double timer;
    final int INTERVALS = 2;

    final double SECONDS_TO_NANOSECONDS_COEFFICIENT = 1000000000.0;
    // length of the interval in seconds
    final double INTERVAL_LENGTH = 10 * SECONDS_TO_NANOSECONDS_COEFFICIENT;
    int intervalCounter = 0;

    // masking time in milliseconds (200)
    final double MASKING_TIME = 0.2 * SECONDS_TO_NANOSECONDS_COEFFICIENT;
    // stimulus time in milliseconds (20)
    final double STIMULUS_TIME = 0.02 * SECONDS_TO_NANOSECONDS_COEFFICIENT;

    boolean stimuliShouldBeDisplayed = false;
    boolean stimuliIsDisplayed = false;
    boolean imageViewShouldBeCleared = false;

    Handler handler;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button);

        if (button != null) {
            button.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        imageView = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        textViewCounter = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textViewCounter);

        // messages are sent to the thread where the Handler was created
        handler = new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

                // not sure if you must always clear the message queue
                this.removeMessages(0);

                double tempStartTime = System.nanoTime();

                // milliseconds are okay
                textViewCounter.setText(String.valueOf(timer / 1000000) + "  ms");

                if (stimuliShouldBeDisplayed && !stimuliIsDisplayed) {

                    stimuliIsDisplayed = true;

                    // show mask
                    imageView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.mask);

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep((long) (MASKING_TIME / 1000000));
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace(

                    // update our timer (milliseconds are okay)
                    timer += System.nanoTime() - tempStartTime;
                    textViewCounter.setText(String.valueOf(timer / 1000000) + "  ms");

                    // show stimulus
                    imageView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.stimulus);

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep((long) (STIMULUS_TIME / 1000000));
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    // update our timer (milliseconds are okay)
                    timer += System.nanoTime() - tempStartTime;
                    textViewCounter.setText(String.valueOf(timer / 1000000) + "  ms");

                    // show mask
                    imageView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.mask);

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep((long) (MASKING_TIME / 1000000));
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    // update our timer (milliseconds are okay)
                    timer += System.nanoTime() - tempStartTime;
                    textViewCounter.setText(String.valueOf(timer / 1000000) + "  ms");
            }

                // clear the imageView
                if (imageViewShouldBeCleared) {
                    imageView.setImageResource(0);
                    imageViewShouldBeCleared = false;
                    stimuliIsDisplayed = false;
                    stimuliShouldBeDisplayed = false;
                }
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (v == button && !buttonWasPressed) {

            buttonWasPressed = true;

            // let's start our timer
            startTime = System.nanoTime();

            Runnable runnableTimeManagement = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    while (currentTime - startTime <= INTERVAL_LENGTH && intervalCounter < INTERVALS) {

                        currentTime = System.nanoTime();

                        timer = currentTime - startTime;

                        // next interval
                        if (timer > INTERVAL_LENGTH) {

                            intervalCounter++;
                            startTime = currentTime;
                            imageViewShouldBeCleared = true;
                        }

                        // 1 seconds extra for the communication time between TimeManagement Thread and GUI Thread
                        if (timer + SECONDS_TO_NANOSECONDS_COEFFICIENT >= INTERVAL_LENGTH - 2 * MASKING_TIME - STIMULUS_TIME) {

                            stimuliShouldBeDisplayed = true;
                        }

                        // we must always create a new empty message
                        Message message = Message.obtain();
                        // we send message to the main UI thread
                        handler.sendMessage(message);

                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(5);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    // time is over
                    buttonWasPressed = false;
                    intervalCounter = 0;
                }
            };

            new Thread(runnableTimeManagement).start();
        }
    }
}
```

Does somebody know a way to precisely control the display time for the images in an alternative way ? The best solution is displaying the stimulus image for only one frame. But I don't know how to have access to the frame rate.

Ist there a possibility to force the UI thread to refresh itself immediately ?

Comment: Given that most phones have a fixed refresh rate - not sure how you can achieve your 20ms stimulus image. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966468/controlling-display-refresh-rate-on-android-device

Comment: As far as I know most phones have a refresh rate of 60 Hz, that would be a rate of 1/60 s = 16.7 ms.

Comment: Yes so either your image is shown for some multiple of the fixed refresh rate:16.7 ms or 33.4 ms. If that is within acceptable tolerance - then sure it should be achievable either in Canvas or OpenGL ES.

Comment: If the image is shown less than 20 ms it's okay, too. But It should not be shown more than 20 ms.

Answer (score 0):

`Thread.sleep` is usually not a good idea. And I'm not sure you need a secondary thread for what you describe. You could simply use [`Handler.sendMessageDelayed`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#sendMessageDelayed(android.os.Message,%20long)) for UI updates to happen in the future:

```
// will run as soon as possible (almost immediately)
handler.sendMessage(handler.obtainMessage(0, R.mimap.mask, 0));
// will run in 200ms
handler.sendMessageDelayed(handler.obtainMessage(0, R.mimap.stimulus, 0), 200);
// will run in 220ms
handler.sendMessageDelayed(handler.obtainMessage(0, R.mimap.mask, 0), 220);
```

And then your handler only displays the image it received in the argument to the message:

```
@Override
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    imageView.setResource(msg.arg1);
}
```

But keep in mind that you don't exactly control the refresh rate, so this won't guarantee that the image will be displayed for exactly 20ms

Comment: Thanks Xavier for your help. Unfortunately It's important, that the image is shown exactly 20 ms.